# R great circle distance function in km

Tags: r, dplyr, euclidean-distance

I have a dataset and a function I use to determine the distance between repeating tag/day points. However I am trying to change the function so the output is in Km distance instead of the original lat/long format

data:

```
     X      Y       Tag        Date
   34.355 -7.662    151401  2015-09-22       
   34.546 -7.016    151401  2015-09-22    
   34.425 -6.987    151401  2015-10-20             
   34.554 -7.803    151402  2015-10-22  
   34.555 -7.803    151402  2015-10-22  
   34.554 -7.804    151402  2015-10-22
```

function:

```
find_max_dist = function(x, y) {
  cbind(x, y) %>% dist %>% as.matrix %>% apply(1, max)
}

# use dplyr to run the function by group and put the result in a column
event.df <- event.df %>%
  group_by(Tag, Date) %>%
  mutate(Sameday_travel = find_max_dist(X, Y))
```

what the output looks like for a group:

```
Sameday_travel  
        0.0918
        0.0918
```

I want this to say 10.13 (that's the distance in kilometers). I've tried replacing dist with distHaversine in the find_max_dist function but get an error for the X column, which doesn't have NA or wrong length. I assume it as to do with the as.matrix but not sure how to fix it??:
Error:
Error in p[, 1] : subscript out of bounds

Comment: which package are you taking `distHaversine` from?

Comment: I'm using the geosphere package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```r
event.df %>%
  group_by(Tag, Date) %>%
  mutate(sdt = if (n() > 1) c(NA, geosphere::distHaversine(cbind(X, Y))/1000) else NA) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 6 x 5
#       X     Y    Tag Date          sdt
#   <dbl> <dbl>  <int> <date>      <dbl>
# 1  34.4 -7.66 151401 2015-09-22 NA    
# 2  34.5 -7.02 151401 2015-09-22 74.9  
# 3  34.4 -6.99 151401 2015-10-20 NA    
# 4  34.6 -7.80 151402 2015-10-22 NA    
# 5  34.6 -7.80 151402 2015-10-22  0.110
# 6  34.6 -7.80 151402 2015-10-22  0.157
```

This provides the distance *per day*, not a max distance (yet). This can be useful if you need to retain anything about it per-day. If you want to cut straight to the max, then you can summarize it either after this or instead:

```r
event.df %>%
  group_by(Tag, Date) %>%
  summarize(
    sdt = if (n() > 1) max(geosphere::distHaversine(cbind(X, Y))/1000) else NA,
    .groups = "drop"
  )
# # A tibble: 3 x 3
#      Tag Date          sdt
#    <int> <date>      <dbl>
# 1 151401 2015-09-22 74.9  
# 2 151401 2015-10-20 NA    
# 3 151402 2015-10-22  0.157

event.df %>%
  group_by(Tag, Date) %>%
  mutate(sdt = if (n() > 1) c(NA, geosphere::distHaversine(cbind(X, Y))/1000) else NA) %>%
  summarize(sdt = if (any(!is.na(sdt))) max(sdt, na.rm = TRUE) else NA) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 3 x 3
#      Tag Date          sdt
#    <int> <date>      <dbl>
# 1 151401 2015-09-22 74.9  
# 2 151401 2015-10-20 NA    
# 3 151402 2015-10-22  0.157
```

Since `geosphere` tends to operate in meters, the `/1000` gives you kilometers.

Comment: Thank you so much that was perfect! Just to understand correctly, if (n() > 1) is saying if the group is greater than 1 do the calculation, and groups="drop" or ungroup() is saying only print the value once, yes?

Comment: `if (n() > 1)` is to avoid the logical error of finding the distance "between" a single point; this could also be done with `group_by(...) %>% filter(n()>1) %>% mutate(sdt = c(NA, geosphere::distHaversine(...)))`. `.groups="drop"` does not *"print the value once"*, `summarize` is already doing that; instead, when you `group_by` and then `summarize`, often the groups are no longer meaningful (since you only have one row per group after summarizing). The default action is to drop the last group listed, but do so with a message. Adding `.groups` is explicit, hides the message.